# Segmentation Fault on double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

So I'm trying to make a method to create a Database. The prototype for the method is as follows

```
int create( Database **data, int data_size, int data_count, void(*free)(void*));
```

The function specifics:
if data is null or data_size is 0, return FAIL
Otherwise initialize data fields based on parameters

One of the data fields in the struct is Bucket **buckets (which is essentially an array of buckets, each with their own keys/values)
to initialize this I did:

```
*((*data)->buckets) = calloc(data_size, sizeof(Bucket));
```

However, I'm getting a segmentation fault from this and I assume it's my use of pointers but I don't see where I've gone wrong with it

EDIT: Solved. had an extra pointer in front of my statement

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), impossible to say from just two lines of code. Probably you didn't allocate memory correctly.  Think about where in memory any pointer is pointing to.

Comment: @MattMcNabb sorry typo, fixed it. And i've ran gdb and the seg fault comes from accessing those fields. I'll add what I'm testing with to OP

Answer (score 1):

`*data_ptr` is never assigned a value. You need to set it before passing it to your method (or let your method allocate it)

either:

`data_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Database));`

or in the method

`*data = malloc(sizeof(Database));`

Comment: Ah okay, I thought the fault was a result of the way i was dereferencing, thank you.

Comment: I also have one more question if you could help me with, I'm updating op